# Sorting group of list Item with ID and creating Sequence No Using JQUERY

Tags: jquery, sorting, sequence

i have two set of unordered list item, i want to sort based on its ID and want to create sequence no.  using jquery.

```
<ul class="mygroup" id="test1">
<li id="4112">blub</li>
<li id="1422">blaaah</li>
<li id="6640">hmmmm</li>
<li id="2221">one more</li>
</ul>
<ul class="mygroup" id="test2">
<li id="7452">BBB</li>
<li id="15">AAA</li>
<li id="7775">CCC</li>
<li id="2444">DDDD</li>
</ul>
```

want to have output like this

```
<ul class="mygroup" id="test1">
<li id="4112">(5)blub</li>
<li id="1422">(2)blaaah</li>
<li id="6640">(6)hmmmm</li>
<li id="2221">(3)one more</li>
</ul>

<ul class="mygroup" id="test2">
<li id="7452">(7)BBB</li>
<li id="15">(1)AAA</li>
<li id="7775">(8)CCC</li>
<li id="2444">(4)DDDD</li>
</ul>
```

i have used  for sorting but i am not getting the way output i want

```
<script src="jquery.js" type="application/javascript" ></script>
<script type="application/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(e) {
        $(function(){
            var elems = $('.mygroup').children('li').remove();

            elems.sort(function(a,b){
                return parseInt(a.id) > parseInt(b.id);
            });

            $('.mygroup').append(elems);
        });
    });
</script>
```

please guide me ?

Comment: your title no using jQuery, but in your question I see jQuery??

Answer (score 0):

You can do it follows

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $(function(){
        $('.mygroup').each(function(){

            var elems = $(this).children('li').detach();
            elems.sort(function (a, b) {
                return parseInt(a.id) > parseInt(b.id);
            });

            $(this).append(elems);

        });

    });
});
```

**[Reference for `.detach()`](http://api.jquery.com/detach/)**. Using `.detach()` will allow you to retain the data after removing it from the DOM unlike when using `.remove()`.

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7p6ypght/)**

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks anubhav, but it is not exact output i want, li position to be remain in same place and it create order no(#). from two set of ul.